# Turning statement into predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

Hey so I had to turn this into predicate logic. A list $l$ is in ascending order. So what i did is

$\forall x.((number(x) \leq length(l)-1) \to elem(l,x) \leq elem(l,x+1))$

so my question is do i have to specify that l is a list?
something like

$\exists l.((list(l))\to(\forall x.((number(x) \leq length(l)-1) \to elem(l,x)\leq elem(l,x+1))) $

Comment: Well, $l$ should be the only free variable in the formula, as in your first one, but we can specify  ${\rm list}(l)\land(\forall x.\,x\in\Bbb N,\,x\le\dots)$... However, I'm not sure that this usage of $x$ as natural number here - such as comparing to the length or applying $x+1$ - is allowed.. Do you have perhaps other examples about how a list is turned into predicate logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $number(x)$ part is weird ... is $number$ supposed to be a predicate? But that can't be right, since you say $number(x) \le length(l)-1$, which would only work if $number(x)$ is an object, and thus $number$ must be a function. But what function?  Your $elem(l,x)$ expression is of course a function that returns the $x$-th element from the list, so you use $x$ as an index ... So then what does $number(x)$ do? Indeed, isn't it just the index $x$ itself that ranges from $1$ to $length(l)-1$? In other words, you should just get rid of that $number$ function, (and also introduce a lower bound to the index), so you get:

$\forall x ((1 \le x \land x \le length(l)-1) \rightarrow elem(l,x) \le elem(l,x+1))$

If you explicitly need to say that $l$ is a list (I really can't answer that question for you), then put $List(l) \land$ in front of that (don't use a quantifier for $l$, and certainly do not use a $\rightarrow$ in combination with a $\exists$)

Comment: i misstyped i wanted to say $number(x) \land x \leq length(l)-1$ i had my doubts about using implication in exists aswell, thank you so much it makes sense now :))

Comment: @asddf Ah yes, if you have lists as well as numbers in the domain, then you need a $Number$ as well as $List$ predicate, so what you have there would work indeed! (I don't know if you have any guidelines on this, but typically I like to have predicates start with a capital letter, and functions with a small letter, so I can easily separate them). Glad I could help! :)